# How do I see the ON DELETE and ON UPDATE for a foreign key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using this query to find foreign key relationships:

```
SELECT *
FROM `information_schema`.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`
WHERE `REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA` = ? AND 
      `TABLE_NAME` = ? AND 
      `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME` IS NOT NULL
```

It's giving me most of what I need, but the two fields I am missing are

1. on update
2. on delete

How do I find those properties on a foreign key constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` table that has the following columns:

```
    CONSTRAINT_CATALOG      
    CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA        
    CONSTRAINT_NAME      
    UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG       
    UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA         
    UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME       
    MATCH_OPTION         
    UPDATE_RULE      
    DELETE_RULE      
    TABLE_NAME       
    REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME
```

By joining on `CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA` and `CONSTRAINT_NAME`, you can get the `UPDATE_RULE` and `DELETE_RULE`.

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/referential-constraints-table.html), in the document.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say, but I assume you're looking for something you can access programmatically?

If not, I'm pretty sure `SHOW CREATE TABLE ?` will give you all the info you're looking for.